# Mobile app for uploading photos

Tags: api, mobile

I am looking for an universal mobile app that would serve for uploading photos from the user's device to any network service that gets registered with that app.

So various service vendors would register their service with the app and the user could use the app to upload his photo easily from the mobile phone to that service.

E.g. let's say I run an OCR service on the internet. I would like to make it easy for my users to make a photo of a document, upload it to my service and run the OCR. But there is no easy way how to do it. As an owner of that OCR service I would like to find another SW vendor that would offer such a generic mobile app that I could use through an API and allow the users to upload their photos to my service through this generic app. I do not want to develop such app by myself.

Is there something like that somewhere?